# SBT java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format

Tags: sbt

A Windows 7 Pro machine was shut down improperly. When the machine came back up, running 'sbt test' resulted in this error:

```
[error] {file:/C:/Jenkins/jobs/job1/workspace/}default-2990ce/copy-resources: Error wrapping InputStream in GZIPInputStream: java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I resolved it by removing the target folder in the project's root directory C:/Jenkins/jobs/job1/workspace/.

Answer (score 15):

I just had this issue after a computer crash and sbt clean didn't help.
Make sure you really find and remove all target directories:

```
 rm -rf `find . -name target`
```

Comment: This also occurs when downgrading `sbt`. For me occurred when going from 1.0 to 13.11